# When an Attribute is set to false, is the property still observable inside the element?

Tags: lit-element

> @ lit-element -> Properties -> Configure attributes -> Configure observed attributes

it refers that:

> By default, LitElement creates a corresponding observed attribute for all declared properties.

and

> To prevent an observed attribute from being created for a property, set attribute to false. The property will not be initialized from attributes in markup, and attribute changes won’t affect it.

**Clarification:**

When an observed attribute is prevented, the property is still observable within the element, isn't it?

Tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The property will still be accessible from within javascript, and will trigger re-renders.